# Changing the pop out feature of the icon bar

Tags: helpfile

I have the ubuntu 11 and the icon bar pops out when I don't want it.  I comes out when I go to the back arrow in the same corner.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option *(according to me atleast)* is to increase the **Edge Reveal Timeout** option in the Ubuntu Unity Plugin in the Compiz Config Settings Manager. That will reveal the Launcher Bar only after the designated time.

1. **[Compiz Config Settings Manager [image: software_center_icon]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ccsm)**  is not installed by default. Click on the link or you could also alternatively run the following to install the package via a terminal (Default keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>)

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ccsm
   ```
2. After that open it and scroll down to Ubuntu Unity Plugin and then increase the Edge Reveal Timeout.

[image: screen_1_ccsm]

[image: plugin_screen]